# cURL in a bash script

Tags: curl

When I run the following cURL command from the command line on Red hat Linux it works and updates the records in the file sis_dave_test2.txt. But when I place it in a bash script that I can create a cron job it fails.

The cURL command and it's output:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -u e243dc9e-e505-4998-9c3c-3faad0add42f:password --url https://bbtest.ucd.ie/webapps/bb-data-integration-flatfile-bb_bb60/endpoint/person/store --data-bin  @sis-dave-test2.txt

error
", this makes an  read data from file "sis-dave-test2.txt
```

please help I have trie adding " \ but cannot get it working
Thanks

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat its possible that the failure to migrate was no matching tag on the target site... flagged the question to check if this is the case.